# Sampling from intersection of sphere and simplex

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling, mathematica

I need to isotropically sample vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ of given Euclidean norm $C$ with a restriction that components are positive and add up to 1. Can someone suggest a method to do it?

I [tried](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-alternating-projections.nb) sampling from sphere/plane intersection and rejecting points outside of the positive orthant, but the efficiency is bad. Unless $d$ is very low, this has almost 100% probability of rejection. Visualized below for $d=3$.

[image]

Comment: Vectors with positive components adding to 1 would form a hyperplane restricted to the positive quadrant (or the higher Dimensional version of a quadrant). The intersection of a sphere with a hyperplane should result in a lower Dimensional sphere. So unless I'm misunderstanding you, you ultimately just want to sample from a sphere, right?

Comment: For $d=3$ and $C=0.9$, it's the intersection of sphere and filled triangle, so the result is 3 disconnected circular regions you can see in the post

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean. In that case, you could calculate the radius of the circle, shift your coordinates to the center of the triangle, calculate the intervals of angles at which the circle and triangle intersect, then sample uniformly from these calculated angular intervals.

Comment: @RaadShaikh the difficulty becomes how to sample uniformly from these angular intervals. In this case, the intervals are 1d, but for $d=4$, intervals will be 2 dimensional. Using rejection sampling in the interval space will have the same efficiency problem

Comment: Perhaps you can try uniform sampling on the simplex and reject those whose norm squared is too large? https://atrium.lib.uoguelph.ca/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10214/25386/uniform_simplex.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Comment: I need points whose norm is c, so I could reject points in simplex that are both too large and too small. This is sort of workable for d=3 but for higher d the efficiency is too low. Unless c=1/sqrt (d) I have almost zero probability of encountering a matching sample